# Optimal query for BigQuery for many fields that array type

Tags: google-bigquery

In the Google BigQuery I've defined table with 5 fields
I'm loading it from json format
The schema is as following, Lets call the table user_data

The Array type in BigQuery is just repitable field

```
userid: String
cats: Array[Int]
features:Array[Long]
segments:Array[Int]
tags:Array[Int]
```

I need to run a query like

```
select count userid
from user_data
where 
 (123,265) in cats and
 (555,666,777) in segments and
 (100, 200) in tags
```

What is the best permormant way to run such query, and what should be a syntax of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. It is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH user_data AS (
  SELECT '1' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[123,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[555,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[1231,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[555,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[123,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[5551,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags 
)
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS count_userid
FROM user_data
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cat) FROM UNNEST(cats) AS cat WHERE cat IN (123, 265)) = 2
AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT segment) FROM UNNEST(segments) AS segment WHERE segment IN (555,666,777)) = 3
AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tag) FROM UNNEST(tags) AS tag WHERE tag IN (100, 200)) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Does it perform OR between values of single dimension?

Comment: It looks for all expected values are in respective dimensions. If you want at least one in each dimension - you should change =2 and =3 to >0

Answer (score 1):

Variation of Mikhail's answer. I believe Julias wants to count users where condition on each dimension is true, i.e. at least one of the constants match. In this case `EXISTS` will be more efficient than `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, i.e.

```
#standardSQL
WITH user_data AS (
  SELECT '1' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[123,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[555,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[1231,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[555,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS userid, ARRAY<INT64>[123,265] AS cats, ARRAY<INT64>[1,2] AS features, ARRAY<INT64>[5551,666,777] AS segments, ARRAY<INT64>[100, 200] AS tags 
)
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS count_userid
FROM user_data
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(cats) cat WHERE cat IN (123, 265))
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(segments) segment WHERE segment IN (555,666,777))
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(tags) tag WHERE tag IN (100, 200))
```